# Old homegrown hops

Tags: hops, bittering, alpha-acids, oxidation

I have been growing and using my own hops for a couple of years now. after harvesting this year I left them out to dry, they have been drying now for a little to long (about two months) they are all brown and papery. just wondering what the effects of being left out are, oxidization? alpha and beta acid loss? should I just toss them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency* will be lower (due to alpha acid degradation) and aromas will be missing, and you'll likely have some cheesy/sweaty off-flavors from isovaleric acid.  Toss them and buy some fresher ones.     *edit:  changed from "utilization".

Comment: I don't think utilization itself would be lower, but IBUs likely would be for the reason you state.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I should have used "efficiency" rather than "utilization".  Correcting the post now.

Answer (score 0):

The effects are pretty much as you state.  Personally, I wouldn't use them.  I guess maybe if you were making a lambic you could use them, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used "expired" hop flakes before, and BeerSensor's characterization of them as having "cheesy/sweaty off-flavors" is absolutely correct.

In that particular batch, an ~6% ABV IPA, the nose was almost entirely absent of Amarillo (the expired hops in question), and there was very little hoppy bitterness.